# How to use REGEXP_REPLACE to check if a value 'Closed' is present in the string and replace

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr, regexp-like

I have the below condition.

**Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Tuesday Closed <.br> Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.**

Here Tuesday is Closed. So i need to exclude the below value from the string '<.br>Tuesday Closed' and generate as :

**Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.**

Tried with REGEXP_REPLACE(OfficeHrs,'Closed',' ') which will only emit the Closed part, but not sure how to ignore the **<.br>** from the string

Comment: is the text always in the middle of the string? is the pattern always the same?

Comment: Pattern is same. The day can change. Any day can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better using `regexp_substr()` instead of `regexp_replace()`, and `instr()`, `regexp_count()` as auxiliary functions, and `listagg()` to concatenate at the end :

```
with tab as
(
 select 'Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.
 Tuesday Closed
 Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m' as str from dual 
), t1 as
(
select regexp_substr(str,'^.*$',1,level,'m') as str, level as lvl
  from tab
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str,chr(10)) + 1
)
select listagg(str,chr(10)) within group (order by lvl) as "Result String"
  from t1
 where instr(str,'Closed')=0;

Result String
---------------------------------
Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.
 Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=129e601bd23ad24133a8cdfce6a71b4e)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can try `/[^(<.br>)]*Closed\s?<\.br>/` to match and then replace it with `''`
Hope it helps

Comment: The question is tagged SQL and Oracle. What's with the forward slashes? That looks rather like `sed` or such, nothing like Oracle SQL. Besides, what do you think `[^(<.br>)]` means? What it does mean is "any single character other than an opening parenthesis, a less-than symbol, a period, the lower-case letter b, the lower-case letter r, a greater-than symbol, or a closing parenthesis". Is that what you thought it means?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
 with tab as(
  select 'Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Tuesday Closed <.br> Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.' as str from dual union all
  select 'Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Tuesday Closed <.br> Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Thursday Closed <.br> Sunday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.' as str from dual union all
  select 'Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Tuesday Closed <.br> Wednesday Closed <.br> Sunday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.' as str from dual
)
select regexp_replace(str,'> [[:alpha:]]* Closed <.br')

from tab;
```

> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'>[[:ALPHA:]]*CLOSED<.BR')                                                            |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.                                     |
> | Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Wednesday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Sunday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. |
> | Monday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. <.br> Sunday 8:30 a.m. to 6:00 p.m.                                        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61df4de32edb82396588f170f2fbd780)*

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected

**regexp_replace(str,'<.br>[[:alpha:]]* Closed')**

Comment: This will work, as long as <.br> are the only possible tags... and also only as long as the days "the business is Closed" are not either the first day or the last day in the list.

Comment: @mathguy that's true. since the pattern is always the same, it should not be a problem